# Is there a way to use wildcard delete with command-line SVN?

Tags: svn, wildcard

In the `tags/` directory of my SVN repo, I have something like:

```
TAG_BUILD_001
TAG_BUILD_002
TAG_BUILD_003
TAG_BUILD_004
...
TAG_BUILD_100
TAG_BUILD_101
...
```

Is there a way to delete, say, everything from `BUILD_001` to `BUILD_099` quickly?

I tried:

```
svn rm https://host/module/tags/TAG_BUILD_0*
```

but that doesn't seem to work and I got the following error:

```
svn: URL 'https://host/module/tags/TAG_BUILD_0*' non-existent in that revision
```

Comment: If not, you could certainly write a simple script to do it for you...

Comment: Sure, I was just wondering if there's any parameter or flags that I might be able to use :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, `svn delete` does take wildcards, but only if you're doing a local delete and not through a URL. The solution is to do a checkout of the tags directory, then delete the tags.

Now, normally, doing this would require gobs of time and multiple gigabytes of space since each tag would represent a revision of your entire project. If each tag is 100 megabytes in size, your checkout would be 10 Gigabytes.

However, the `svn co` command now takes the `--depth` parameter:

```
$ svn checkout --depth immediates https://host/module/tags svn-tags
```

Now, you'll checkout all of the tags, but none of their contents. That takes only a few minutes to checkout and almost no room on your computer since these are all empty directories. Now, you can use:

```
$ cd svn-tags
$ svn rm TAG_BUILD_00*
$ svn commit -m"Removed tags 000 through 099"
```

And, best of all, it's all done in a single revision.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shell:

```
for i in $(seq -w 1 13)
do
  echo "https://host/module/tags/TAG_BUILD_$i"
done
```

Run it and take a look at the commands you generated. If you're sure this is really what you want to do, pipe the output to `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `svn rm` does not take wildcards as input. That may be the problem. You have to delete the tags one by one, specifying the actual full tags name:

```
svn rm https://host/module/tags/TAG_BUILD_001
```

Now, if you have a visual tool (such as TortoiseSVN), you can select the tags you want to delete and them, delete them.

Last, but not least, when you use `svn rm` you have to remember to commit. Any questions, look [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html).